# Skype link to echo123

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, skype

I'm trying to insert a link in a html page such that when you click it, skype calls "echo test service". Does "callto://echo123" work on all browser and almost operating system? Could I show a nice error if there isn't skype installed?
I've read about skypedetection in js but it disappeared from skype site...

Comment: You probably already know this. Still its worthwhile to note that skype plugin is available only for IE, FF and Chrome - i.e. this feature will work only if your client is using one of those browsers PLUS has the skype plugin installed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better to use the Skype URI Scheme (Skype:echo123?call) this works on mac on windows, I don't have Linux to check it but it should work here to. callto:// is a generic handler used by many voip calling software where as Skype uri will only work with the Skype client.

Note that support for this scheme is limited on mobile platforms.

more info : https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri

Thanks